# Problema de conexão ao Banco de dados com Docker

Tags: php, postgresql, docker

Migrei minha aplicação para um container Docker, ela estava funcionando tudo certo, até que um momento eu tive que mudar os scripts de população do banco e recriei o banco, porém tive este problema que eu não sei como resolver, já tentei modificar as portas, porém não entendi direito.

Segue o erro:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message
>   'SQLSTATE[08006] [7] could not connect to server: Connection
>   refused\n\tIs the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and
>   accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?\ncould not connect to
>   server: Network is unreachable\n\tIs the server running on host
>   "localhost" (::1) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?'
>   in /app/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php:129\nStack trace:\n#0
>   /app/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(129):
>   PDO->__construct('pgsql:host=loca...', 'postgres', '1234', Array)\n#1
>   /app/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Pgsql.php(87):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->_connect()\n#2
>   /app/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(861):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Pgsql->_connect()\n#3
>   /app/library/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Pgsql.php(171):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->quote('CaSettings')\n#4
>   /app/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(836):
>   Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Pgsql->describeTable('CaSettings', NULL)\n#5
>   /app/library/Zend/Db/Table/Abstract.php(858):
>   Zend_Db_Table_Abstract->_setup in
>   /app/library/Zend/Controller/Plugin/Broker.php on line 312

Meu docker-compose.yml
    version: '3'

```
services:
    db:
        environment:
            - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
            - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=1234
            - POSTGRES_DB=saec_dev
        image: postgres
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
            - ./code/application/modules/db/sql/createDatabase.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/createDatabase.sql
            - ./code/application/modules/db/sql/populateDatabase.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/populateDatabase.sql
        ports:
            - "5432:5432"

    saec:
        build: .
        depends_on:
            - db
        ports:
            - '40444:40444'
        volumes:
            - ./code:/app
volumes:
    db-data:
```

Comment: Dentro do container da aplicação - `saec` - não tem banco mesmo, então você não tem que se conectar em `localhost`. Só alterar sua string de conexão, altere `localhost` para `db`.

Comment: @BrunoCésar Show, era exatamente isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pela mensagem de erro você está tentando conectar num postgres local:

> Network is unreachable\n\tIs the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting\n\tTCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Acontece que no *container* que você está rodando sua aplicação realmente não tem nenhum serviço atendendo nesta porta, já que o serviço do postgresql está rodando em um outro *container*.

Para fazer isto basta alterar a sua *string* de conexão ao banco para ao invés de usar `localhost` usar `db`. Como os *containers* estão na mesma *compose* e por conseguinte na mesma rede ele conseguir resolver ele nome/*alias*.